# Update with where ANSI join syntax in PostgreSQL updates all rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to do an update with joins in the where clause. I understand with PostgreSQL there is a from clause that I can use with implicit joins like this:

```
update tbl1 t1 set name = 'foo'
from tbl2 t2
where t2.id = t1.table2_id
and t2.region = 'bar'
```

However, I have existing code that generates ANSI joins instead of implicit joins. Looking around Stack Overflow, I read that I could do something like this:

```
update tbl1 set name = 'foo' 
from tbl1 t1 
inner join tbl2 t2 on t2.id = t1.table2_id 
where t2.region = 'bar'
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, and instead of updating just 2 rows, it updates all the rows, regardless of what's in the from/where clause.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a side effect that is caused due to the reason that it treats `t1` as a different table than the one that is being updated. There are 2 ways of getting around this.

1. Use the first query that you posted to `UPDATE`.
2. Add a condition to the second query like `tbl1.id = t1.id` so that it forces 1 to 1 mapping of the table being updated.